# How to iterate through a Userlist in android RecyclerView and save CheckBox changes on a Firestore Database with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying for few days to find a solution , but I can not find the hot potato.

I have about 200 users in attendance list for a sports club.
The checkbox should store which users are present.
The problem is that I can only manage only one user.
I try a lot but no result
Anybody have an idea how to solve this problem please?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to

> @Sanlok Lee

Problem successfully resolved.

Below the new code:

class User:

```
    class User(
    val uid: String?,
    val username: String?,
    val profileImageUrl: String?,
    val isSelected: Boolean?
)  {

    constructor() : this("", "", "", false)
}
```

class Home:

```
class Home : AppCompatActivity() {
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val adapter = PerformListAdapter()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_perform_anwesenheitsliste)

    verifyUserIsLogin()

    _recyclerView_show_anwesenheitsliste.adapter = adapter

    showUsersAndPerformChekBoxes()
}

fun showUsersAndPerformChekBoxes() {
    db.collection("users")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            val users = documents.map { doc ->
                doc.toObject(User::class.java)
            }
            adapter.submitUsers(users)
        }
}

private fun verifyUserIsLogin() {
    val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
    if (uid == null) {
        val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    when (item?.itemId) {

        R.id.menu_home -> {}
        R.id.menu_sign_out -> {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
            val intent = Intent(this, RegisterActivity::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.nav_menu_home, menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
}
```

class PerformListAdapter:

```
class PerformListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<PerformListAdapter.CustomViewHolder>() {
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    var users: List<User> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {

        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val itemuViewRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_row, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(itemuViewRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (users.size > position) {
            holder.bindTo(users[position])
        } else {
            holder.clear()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return users.size
    }

    fun submitUsers(users: List<User>) {
        this.users = users
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class CustomViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        private val checkBox_select: CheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id._checkBox_select)
        private val textView_anwesenheitsliste_username =
            view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id._textView_anwesenheitsliste_username)

        private val imageView_show_anwesenheitsliste_row =
            view.findViewById<CircleImageView>(R.id._imageView_show_anwesenheitsliste_row)

        private val checkedChangeListener = CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->

            val uid = users[adapterPosition].uid

            if (uid != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, uid)
                if (isChecked) {
                    db.collection("users")
                        .document(uid)
                        .update("selected", true)
                } else {
                    db.collection("users")
                        .document(uid)
                        .update("selected", false)
                }
            }
        }

        fun bindTo(user: User) {
            if (!user.profileImageUrl!!.isEmpty()) {
                Picasso.get().load(user.profileImageUrl)
                    .into(imageView_show_anwesenheitsliste_row)
            }
            textView_anwesenheitsliste_username?.text = user.username
            checkBox_select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
            checkBox_select.isChecked = (user.isSelected == true)
            checkBox_select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener)
        }

        fun clear() {
            textView_anwesenheitsliste_username.text = ""
            checkBox_select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you are not familiar with how `RecyclerView` works. `adapter.setOnItemClickListener` sets click listener for all items in the list, not just a single item, so it doesn't make sense to put it inside the for-loop. There isn't any simple fix for this because the code is structurally incorrect. Please update your question with your implementation of `GroupAdapter` and `User` class, so that people can help you with that part.

Comment: Thanks Lee, I update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to think about is whether you need a click listener for this. The click event should be absorbed by the `CheckBox` and therefore click listener is probably not needed. Also, `setOnCheckedChangeListener` should be set once per `CheckBox` not per click nor per `User` items.

Since you haven't showed us `GroupAdapter` nor `ViewHolder` implementation, so I just came up with one possible implementation:

GroupAdapter.kt

```
class GroupAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<GroupAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    private var users: List<User> = ArrayList() // Store user list here


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourViewHolderLayout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (users.size > position)
            holder.bindTo(users[position])
        else
            holder.clear()
    }


    override fun getItemCount() = users.size


    // Update the user list
    fun submitUsers(users: List<User>) {
        this.users = users
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    inner class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        private val _checkBox_select: CheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.yourCheckBoxId)
        private val _textView_anwesenheitsliste_username = view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextBoxId)
        private val checkedChangeListener =
            CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { view, isChecked ->
                val uid = users[adapterPosition].uid

                if (uid != null) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        db.collection("users").document(uid)
                            .update("isSelected", true)
                    } else {
                        db.collection("users").document(uid)
                            .update("isSelected", false)
                    }
                }
            }


        // bind to user here
        fun bindTo(user: User) {

            if (!user.prfileImageUrl!!.isEmpty()) {
                Picasso.get().load(user.prfileImageUrl)
                    .into(_imageView_show_anwesenheitsliste_row)
            }
            _textView_anwesenheitsliste_username.text = user.username
            _checkBox_select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
            _checkBox_select.isChecked = (user.isSelected == true)
            _checkBox_select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener)
        }


        // clear
        fun clear() {
            _textView_anwesenheitsliste_username.text = ""
            _checkBox_select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use this adapter in your activity like this:

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val adapter = GroupAdapter()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_perform_anwesenheitsliste)

     _recyclerView_show_anwesenheitsliste.adapter = adapter

    showUsersAndPerformChekBoxes()
}

private fun showUsersAndPerformChekBoxes() {
    db.collection("users")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            val users = documents.map { doc -> doc.toObejct(User::Class.java) }
            adapter.submitUsers(users)
        }
}
```

Things might not work straight off since I haven't tested the code.

**Further improvements**

If you are interested, think about these scenarios: What if there are too many users that the app cannot get the entire list all at once? What if there are multiple phones that run the same app and try to update the list all at the same time? What if there is a network problem? What happens if the user spams the checkbox x9999 times?

The solutions for these problems are not trivial so I am not answering here, but it is a good practice to think about edge cases and how the app should react to those scenarios.

Comment: Thanks  again!, i really appreciate it.
I will apply your recommendations and report back to you.
Now is the time to dive into the topic.